# Radio buttons reset/randomize on changing activity

Tags: java, android

My friend and I are making a movie library app, and we came across a weird issue.

In our main Activity list we have a status "watched" and not watched", which is selected in the edit activity we made, where you can select if the movie is watched or not in a radio group.

But for some reason when the movie is watched, sometimes in a weird random way, if we click on that movie in the edit Activity it changes to watched on the radio buttons, and vice versa.

Its not consinstant, sometime it works and sometimes it toggles.

Here is the mainactivity code for the status:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int pos,
        long id) {

    Log.d(TAG, "id=" + id);

    TextView statusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_movie_status);
    String status = statusText.getText().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "status is " + status);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ManualEditActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);

    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    intent.putExtra("status", status);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And this is the code for receiving the intent in the edit activity:

```
status = callIntent.getStringExtra("status");
        Log.d(TAG, "status is " + status);
        Log.d("checking rating2", rate + "");
        if ((status).equals("Watched")) {
            radioWatchYes.setChecked(true);
            radioWatchNo.setChecked(false);

        } else if ((status).equals("Not Watched")){
            radioWatchYes.setChecked(false);
            radioWatchNo.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
```

I have no idea what's causing this randomization.

Thanks!

Comment: what does your getView on the listview adapter look like?

Comment: We made a custom adapter

Comment: my point is that maybe somewhere in your custom adapter there's a bug that makes the status text wrong when you try to get it.

Comment: I have checked it , and everything seems fine. It's very weird.

Comment: without looking at the code it's hard to tell what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Baseadapter then put this code before getview()

```
@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() 
        {

            if (list.size() > 1) 
            {
                return list.size();
            } 
            else 
            {
                return super.getViewTypeCount();
            }

        }
```